# Camel FTP doesn't move processed files if not in root folder

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I looked at all the camel ftp answers here and no option worked for me.

Camel FTP (no spring starter) not moving the files after processing and I am not sure why.

using camel 3.6.0

logging is on.

I am using a nested folder /x/y/z location under ftp

```
noop=true
idempotent=true
move=./done
```

I tried all combinations of move path, noop, idempotent I could think of.

My user has full access to move files and create a folder on this FTP server.

tried:

```
move = folder
move = .folder
move = .done
move = ./.done
move =/x/y/z/done
```

What am I missing?

no errors in log.

Answer (score 0):

noop was set to true so it will not move the file.

```
noop=false
```

fixed it.